# How to set Labels for GroupBars in BarChart?

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) for showing BarChart.

I want to show labels for GroupBars, not for individual bars.

This is my two `BarDataSet`. (I am using SQLite to get values, so I can show the code for this)

[image]

I have added these is my code to add the two `BarDataSet`.

```
BarDataSet expenseBarDataSet = new BarDataSet(expenseAmounts, "Expense");
expenseBarDataSet.setColors(Color.RED);
expenseBarDataSet.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
BarDataSet incomeBarDataSet = new BarDataSet(incomeAmounts, "Income");
incomeBarDataSet.setColors(Color.GREEN);
incomeBarDataSet.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);

BarData barData = new BarData(expenseBarDataSet, incomeBarDataSet);
barData.setValueTextSize(12f);
barData.setValueFormatter(new LargeValueFormatter());
```

This is the code for the BarChart

```
customDatesBarChart.setData(barChartExpenseData.getBarData());  //getBarData will return the above BarData
customDatesBarChart.groupBars(0f, 0.5f, 0f);
customDatesBarChart.getData().setHighlightEnabled(false);
customDatesBarChart.setDescription(null);
customDatesBarChart.setPinchZoom(false);
customDatesBarChart.setScaleEnabled(false);
customDatesBarChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
customDatesBarChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
customDatesBarChart.getXAxis().setAxisMaximum(0 + customDatesBarChart.getBarData().getGroupWidth(0.5f, 0f) * barChartExpenseData.count());
customDatesBarChart.invalidate();

Legend barChartLegend = customDatesBarChart.getLegend();
barChartLegend.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.TOP);
barChartLegend.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
barChartLegend.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
barChartLegend.setDrawInside(true);
barChartLegend.setYOffset(20f);
barChartLegend.setXOffset(0f);
barChartLegend.setYEntrySpace(0f);
barChartLegend.setTextSize(12f);
barChartLegend.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

XAxis xAxis = customDatesBarChart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setAxisLineColor(Color.WHITE);
xAxis.setGridColor(Color.WHITE);
xAxis.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
xAxis.setTextSize(12f);
xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
xAxis.setAxisMinimum(0);
xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(barChartExpenseData.getCategories()));  // getCategories will return the labels, for example cat1, cat2
xAxis.setLabelCount(barChartExpenseData.getBarData().getEntryCount());

customDatesBarChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
YAxis yAxis = customDatesBarChart.getAxisLeft();
yAxis.setAxisLineColor(Color.WHITE);
yAxis.setGridColor(Color.WHITE);
yAxis.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
yAxis.setValueFormatter(new LargeValueFormatter());
yAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
yAxis.setTextSize(12f);
yAxis.setSpaceTop(35f);
yAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);
```

This is my output

[image]

As you can see the cat1 and cat2 are the labels of GroupBars but it is showing for individual bars.

**How to set Labels for GroupBars in BarChart?**

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46021471/grouping-datasets-in-mpandroid-charts/46073356#46073356

Answer (score 0):

Use version 3.0.1 and follow example below:

```
    barWidth = 0.3f;
    barSpace = 0f;
    groupSpace = 0.4f;

    chart = (BarChart)findViewById(R.id.barChart);
    chart.setDescription(null);
    chart.setPinchZoom(false);
    chart.setScaleEnabled(false);
    chart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
    chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

    int groupCount = 6;

    ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();

    xVals.add("Jan");
    xVals.add("Feb");
    xVals.add("Mar");
    xVals.add("Apr");
    xVals.add("May");
    xVals.add("Jun");

    ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
    ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals2 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();

    yVals1.add(new BarEntry(1, (float) 1));
    yVals2.add(new BarEntry(1, (float) 2));
    yVals1.add(new BarEntry(2, (float) 3));
    yVals2.add(new BarEntry(2, (float) 4));
    yVals1.add(new BarEntry(3, (float) 5));
    yVals2.add(new BarEntry(3, (float) 6));
    yVals1.add(new BarEntry(4, (float) 7));
    yVals2.add(new BarEntry(4, (float) 8));
    yVals1.add(new BarEntry(5, (float) 9));
    yVals2.add(new BarEntry(5, (float) 10));
    yVals1.add(new BarEntry(6, (float) 11));
    yVals2.add(new BarEntry(6, (float) 12));

    BarDataSet set1, set2;
    set1 = new BarDataSet(yVals1, "A");
    set1.setColor(Color.RED);
    set2 = new BarDataSet(yVals2, "B");
    set2.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    BarData data = new BarData(set1, set2);
    data.setValueFormatter(new LargeValueFormatter());

    //X-axis
    XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
    xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
    xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xAxis.setAxisMaximum(6);
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(xVals));

    //Y-axis
    chart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
    YAxis leftAxis = chart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.setValueFormatter(new LargeValueFormatter());
    leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
    leftAxis.setSpaceTop(35f);
    leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);

    // create a MarkerView
    //           MyMarkerView mv = new MyMarkerView(this, R.layout.custom_marker);
    //        chart.setMarker(mv);

    chart.setData(data);
    chart.getBarData().setBarWidth(barWidth);
    chart.getXAxis().setAxisMinimum(0);
    chart.getXAxis().setAxisMaximum(0 + chart.getBarData().getGroupWidth(groupSpace, barSpace) * groupCount);
    chart.groupBars(0, groupSpace, barSpace);
    chart.getData().setHighlightEnabled(false);
    chart.invalidate();
```

Uncomment following line from your code and check if it changes anything:

```
// customDatesBarChart.getBarData().setBarWidth(barWidth);
```

Comment: Sorry for the late replay. Didn't solve the problem, still looks same.

Comment: It should work buddy I shared working example with you look carefully may be you are missing something.

Comment: Bro, it didn't work. You can see my full code [here](https://github.com/Vijay-Nirmal/Expense-Tracker/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/savss/expensetracker/DashboardFragment.java#L85)

Comment: Buddy for group bar chart you have to create multiple data sets. I think you are creating one data set only. I cant find out in your code that where you are creating datasets.

Comment: `getCustomDateTransactionData` will return `BarChartExpenseData`. You can see multiple data sets createn [here](https://github.com/Vijay-Nirmal/Expense-Tracker/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/savss/expensetracker/BarChartExpenseData.java#L22)

Comment: Buddy uncomment this line from your code :   // customDatesBarChart.getBarData().setBarWidth(barWidth);

Comment: I commented this line in above provided example of mine it creates issues so may be thats the case with u too ...